# Select rows with a column equal to 1 OR those that are referenced in an other table

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I have 2 tables A and B, as so:

```
A:                   B:

    A_id | Val      B_id | A_id
    ------------     ------------
    1    | 1         1    | 1
    2    | 1         2    | 1
    3    | 2         3    | 2
    4    | 1         4    | 2
    5    | 3         5    | 5
                     6    | 1
```

I would like to select rows from A where Val = 1 OR those that are referenced in B.
So for this particular example, the select would retrieve:

```
A_id | Val
----------
1    | 1
2    | 1
4    | 1
5    | 3
```

Note that row 4 is not referenced in table B, but Val is equal to one, and Val from row 5 is != 1 but the row is referenced in table B.

I tried using the DISTINCT keyword but the problem is that it doesn't select row 4 because it is not referenced in table B.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I have other columns in table A but to simplify the question I hide them.

Comment: You have tables A and B, and you want a query to return C. Show us C.

Comment: Okay I added the returned table, basically its table A filtered (there is a lot more info in table A but again for simplicity I hide them)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
WHERE A.Val = 1
   OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.A_id = A.A_id);
```